# winbind id command doesn't show user info

Tags: linux, login, samba, active-directory

I added a RedHat 7 machine to AD with winbind.

```
[root@redhat7 ~]# net ads info
LDAP server: <ldap_server_ip>
LDAP server name: <ldapservername>.<domain>.com
Realm: <DOMAIN>
Bind Path: dc=dc,dc=DOMAIN,dc=COM
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Wed, 25 Dec 2019 15:13:56 +03
KDC server: <kdc_ip>
Server time offset: 0
Last machine account password change: Wed, 25 Dec 2019 10:17:39 +03

[root@redhat7 ~]# net ads testjoin
Join is OK.

[root@redhat7 ~]# wbinfo -u
user1
user2
...
```

But when I tried "id user1" command:

```
[root@redhat7 ~]# id user1
id: user1: no such user
```

Why I cannot see the user info and how can I fix that issue? Because of this problem I cannot login to the server also.

Edit: wbinfo output:

```
# wbinfo -S S-1-5-21-......-....-... (myuser sid)
failed to call wbcSidToUid: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
Could not convert sid S-1-5-21-.....-.....-...... to uid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping does not work correctly. We should remove trivia db and mapping files with below commands:

```
#service winbind stop
#service smb stop
#net cache flush
#rm -f /var/lib/samba/*.tdb
#rm -f /var/lib/samba/group_mapping.ldb
#systemctl start winbind
#systemctl start smb
```

Here it is my smb.conf, idmap lines:

```
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range = 10000 - 20000
```

After that winbind will can check id from Active Directory.

Comment: Solved the exact same problem on my openSUSE 15.2 box. THANKS :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, whilst you are using winbind, you are also using sssd. If you are, you should also be aware that you cannot use sssd with Samba >= 4.8.0.
If this was Debian, I would suggest installing 'libnss-winbind libpam-winbind libpam-krb5', but as this is red hat, not sure, but I think they call then 'winbind-clients'

It might help if you posted your [global] part of your smb.conf

Comment: it was redhat. we solved the problem actually, i'll add the solution. But for knowledge, I don't use sssd. The problem was about sid and gid mapping and we flush the config and regenerate the id maps with a command. I'll share the command asap. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you ran 'net cache flush' but I cannot think what command you used to 'regenerate' the id maps, as these are set by the 'idmap config'  lines in smb.conf, I still think it would be a good idea if you posted your smb.conf.

Comment: I answered the question. You can check. It was about id mapping. I don't know what is the problem but the solution is below.

Comment: Those idmap config lines, whilst correct are also wrong ;-)

Comment: The (*) default domain is meant for the Well Known SIDs and anything outside the domain, you should add lines for DOMAIN as well, see here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member